# carrierwave undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have the following error implementing carrierwave in order to upload images

gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0' 
Rails 5.0.1
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

My model:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord

  mount_uploader :cover, CompanyAvatarUploader
  attr_accessor :cover
```

My CompanyAvatarUploader

```
   class CompanyAvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    storage :file
    def store_dir
       "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end
       def extension_whitelist
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end
   end
```

My company_controller.erb

```
class CompanyController < ApplicationController

   def create

       @company = Company.new(company_params)

       respond_to do |format|

         if @company.save
           format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company saved...'}
           format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @company}
         else
           format.html { render new}
           format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

         end
private

def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:name, :address, :country, :telephone, :cover)
  end

end
```

My new.html.erb

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :country %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :country %>
</p>


<p>
  <%= f.label :cover %><br>
  <%= f.file_field :cover %>
</p>
```

My show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Country:</strong>
  <%= @company.country %>
</p>
<p>
  <%=    image_tag @company.cover.url  %>
</p>
```

When I am trying to add a new company with the cover I have the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Company#show
Showing 

app/views/company/show.html.erb where line #22 raised:

undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #22):


</p>
<p>
  <%=    image_tag @company.cover.url %>
</p>
```

The company information is storaged in my MySQL but not the cover

Thank you for your help

Comment: Looks like `@company.cover.url` return `nil` add `<%= debug(@company.cover) %>` and check result.

Comment: nothing, the same is returning

Comment: it's obvious that `@company.cover` return `nil`, that's your problem.

Comment: yes i know that... but why? looks everything in the correct place...

Comment: No, it's not correct, your records is not saving `cover` and its become `nil`.

Comment: Is `attr_accessor :cover` meant to be there?

Comment: the attr_accessor :cover , is in the Model

Comment: I can see that, is it meant to be there? It's not done like that in the readme for carrierwave.